# Restyled select won't line up

Tags: css, image, select, margin

For the first time i needed to restyle some dropdown select menu's. Only they leave me with a problem.
I can't seem to get them lined up with the submit image. Anyone got any tips? Maybe i'm overlooking something simple.

```
<body>
            <div class="filterbalk">
                <form>
                    <label>
                        <select style="width: 250px;">
                            <option>Woningtype</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <select style="width: 250px;">
                           <option>Plaats</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <select style="width: 90px;">
                           <option value="0">Prijs van</option>
                           <option value="0">0</option>
                           <option value="100">100</option>
                           <option value="200">200</option>
                           <option value="300">300</option>
                           <option value="400">400</option>
                           <option value="500">500</option>
                           <option value="600">600</option>
                           <option value="700">700</option>
                           <option value="800">800</option>
                           <option value="900">900</option>
                           <option value="1000">1000</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <select style="width: 90px;">
                           <option value="1000000000">Prijs tot</option>
                           <option value="100">100</option>
                           <option value="200">200</option>
                           <option value="300">300</option>
                           <option value="400">400</option>
                           <option value="500">500</option>
                           <option value="600">600</option>
                           <option value="700">700</option>
                           <option value="800">800</option>
                           <option value="900">900</option>
                           <option value="1000">1000</option>
                           <option value="1000000000">1000+</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                    <input type="image" src="http://www.wauwwebdesign.nl/problem/buttonFilter.jpg" value="Filter" id="submit">
                </form>
            </div>
```

Both HTML and CSS can be found in the fiddle. I can't seem to paste the CSS here.

http://jsfiddle.net/5FcLf/

Comment: Please post **some** HTML & CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need to add is

```
#submit {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/5FcLf/5/)

Then tweak...

Comment: See... overlooking something as simple as this! Thx!